# env variable set by C program, was not able to retrieve from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

**C Program: (File name: temp.c)**

```
main ()
{
  putenv ("VERSION");
  setenv ("VERTSION","1.0",1);
  printf ("%s\n\r",getenv ("VERSION");

  exit (0);
}
```

**output of Cprogram:**
1.0

==========================================================

**Bash Script:**

```
./temp
echo "Ver from bash:"$VERSION
```

**output of bashscript:**

```
1.0                        **(from c program)**
Ver from bash:             **(from bash shell, why wont $VERSION get output here?)**
```

Comment: IIRC, the environment used by a running program is just a copy of the environment at the point of execution - and it's discarded when the program finishes.  There is probably an API to set the global environment, but I don't know how to point you to it.

Comment: You C code doesn't even compile...

Comment: @theGleep A process can only change its own environment, not any other process. When you fork a child process it inherits a copy of the parent's environment.

Comment: This is why programs like `tset` have to be executed using `eval`. They print the variable assignment statements, and the calling shell executes them with `eval`.

Comment: @Bamar - so I was right in the main...but wrong about a possible workaround.  Makes sense when you think about it... the environment belongs to the shell, and there are lots of different shells.  Doesn't make sense to expect an API to set environment variables for *ALL* of the different shells